# Lock branch but allow gitlab merge request

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks

We are using GitLab version 8.5.0. I am writing a custom server side update hook to lock specific branches. It works great, however, I would like to allow GitLab merge requests to be processed. All GitLab merge requests will usually  have "See Merge request" comment in the commit description. Hence, I thought to allow only those commits, which contains commit message "See Merge request". However, it doesnt work the way I thought.

Any other possible ways to allow only gitlab merge requests?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

GIT_COMMIT_MSG=`git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s`

if [[ "$1" == refs/heads/master ]]; then
if [[ "$GIT_COMMIT_MSG" =~ *"See Merge request"* ]]; then
    echo "This is GitLab Merge Request"
else
    echo $GIT_COMMIT_MSG
    echo "ERROR:  you are not allowed to update master" >&2
    exit 1
fi

fi
```

Comment: If you allow any commits with the text `See Merge request` to get through, then what would stop a malicious user from inserting this text to spoof your scripts?

Comment: I know this is not a right way.. I am open for suggestions if there is any other right mechanism to track gitlab commit

Answer (score 9):

I understand you are using GitLab 8.5, but if possible, consider upgrading to 8.11 where this has been natively (and more securely) implemented.
See "[Using the Allowed to merge and Allowed to push settings](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html#using-the-allowed-to-merge-and-allowed-to-push-settings)"

> You could set "`Allowed to push`" to "`No one`", and "`Allowed to merge`" to "`Developers + Masters`", **to require everyone to submit a merge request for changes going into the protected branch**.

[image]

Then all you need is to protect some branches, and they will be modified only through merge request.

Comment: Incidentally, for anyone *not* using GitLab, I have my own sample pre-receive script that does this same kind of thing (calling the allowed users "maintainers" and "supermaintainers"). It has a lot more tweakable knobs. The script is at http://web.torek.net/torek/git/pre-receive.sh.txt

Comment: Thanks, Glad to know locking is implemented in later version. Unfortunately upgrading is not an option right now.